# ubuntu shuts down after exact 5 hours

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 with Kernel 4.2.0-25-generic.

My hardware:

asrock q1900m
nvidia geforce 510
Digital Devices Cine S2

I use the ubuntu for vdr and xbmc.

The Problem is that the pc shuts down after exact 5 hours (and 2 seconds):

```
Jan 30 08:13:02 privat-leo-receiver rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="696" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 30 13:13:04 privat-leo-receiver rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="696" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan 30 15:24:20 privat-leo-receiver rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="642" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 30 20:24:22 privat-leo-receiver rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="642" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

I monitor the temp of the CPU and the motherboard so its not an overheating problem.

I tried to update the nvidia driver to nvidia-352, because I found an thread at a forum that this could be the solution, but it still occurs...

While the 5 fours I let xbmc play an serie in an loop, I will try now with just idle.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. VDR has a feature which shutdowns the system after a configurable time of inactivity, default is 5 hours...